# How to write cloudformation using private AMI rather than public AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

I want to write a cloudformation using yaml file. I know the format for a public AMI. But I get lost in how to add a private AMI in the yaml file. I searched the solution online and someone recommend to use AWS system manager service. I want to ask is there a way to avoid using the system manager service to achieve setting up my yaml file. Here is my yaml file for your reference.

```
AmiId:
  Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
  AllowedValues: ['%list of my public AMI%
                 '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2',
                 '/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2017-English',
                 'ami-id']
                  'ami-id' this is where to insert my private Ami .
                  Default: 'ami-id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't mix** the `AllowedValues` like you do now. You either use `ami-ids` or parameter store values. If you don't want to use parameter store values, then you just use `ami-ids`:

```
AmiId:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id
  AllowedValues: [ami-id1, ami-id2, ami-id3]
  Default: ami-id1
```

Comment: @baolongtougu No problem. If it works, then acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.